# Actual performance of UICollectionView is really bad

Tags: swift, performance, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am currently working on a project and basically, I am still learning.

I was using at the beginning a `UITableView`, but I needed automatic height and 2 or 3 columns (depending on the device).
For the columns, I am using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. 
In general, I am using only `Labels` and `StackViews`; a few warnings like `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` (but I changed in a few ones priorities and is working but the performance is still really bad.

I am not retrieving info from backend, nothing spectacular.

The `CustomLayout` as follows:

```
public protocol CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate: class {
    func numberOfColumns() -> Int
    func height(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}

public class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    private let cellPadding: CGFloat = 4
    public var cache: [IndexPath : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    public weak var flowDelegate: CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate?

    public override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.contentWidth, height: self.contentHeight)
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributesArray = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        if cache.isEmpty {
            self.prepare()
        }
        for (_, layoutAttributes) in self.cache {
            if rect.intersects(layoutAttributes.frame) {
                layoutAttributesArray.append(layoutAttributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributesArray
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return self.cache[indexPath]
    }

    public override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        cache.removeAll()
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
            return
        }
        let numberOfColumns = self.flowDelegate?.numberOfColumns() ?? 1
        self.contentHeight = 0
        let columnWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(numberOfColumns) - CGFloat(numberOfColumns-1) * cellPadding
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            let photoHeight = self.flowDelegate?.height(at: indexPath) ?? 1
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            self.cache[indexPath] = attributes
            self.contentHeight = max(self.contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
    }

    public override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I do need the 2 or 3 columns with the automatic height. But what is really important as in any other project: `Performance`.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the body of your question, not as an external link.

Comment: I added the `CustomLayout`, maybe is there the performance issue...

Comment: Thanks for including the code. Many people can't visit external links, and it's also really annoying because *who knows* where those links go or if they'll expire later on.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice. Should I remove the `[link](google.com)` and better leave the link as this: `google.com`?

Comment: Links are fine for certain things, like a reference, a package, or other things. They're not great for the code you're working on. The goal here is to keep your question as self-contained as possible. External links can and will expire or change, so it's important that the essential parts of your question remain intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that on my `ViewControllers`, on the `func height(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` `protocol`, I was calculating the height each time, instead of only retrieving it from an array.